# Find internal link with input and create anchor click event

Tags: jquery, html, hash, input, dictionary

How can I find internal link with input and create anchor click event with jquery.

Comment: You need to give us more details if you want an answer

Answer (score 0):

Q1: **How can I find internal link with input**

i Dont understand what does this mean so i cant answer this.

Q2: **create anchor click event with jquery.**

```
<a href='javascript:' id="myAnchor">my anchor</a>



jQuery('#myAnchor').bind('click',function(){

    //my codes

});
```

Comment: <form onSubmit="window.location=this.url.value;return false;">
   <input type="search" results="10" name="url" size="20" />
   <input  onclick="document.getElementById('myLink').click()" type="button" value="GO!" />
   </form>
   <li><a href="?New York" id="myLink" rel="p-1768-933">New York</a></li>